# Hazelcast Cluster Not able to Connect to Kubernetes Master

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, hazelcast

I have redeployed one of my already working application after AKS upgrade .
Now my pods are not able to communicate amongst each other saying that could not connect to Kubernetes Master . I have tried externalising port 5701 in my service and deployment .
What could be the possible cause for this ?

```
2023-07-25 11:40:15.703 | forecast-management-service | main | ERROR | w.p.i.c.IAMCCMControlsConfigBaseListener |  | Unable to find SCM configuration for IAMEnvControlsConfig, default value for properties will be used and no property will be read from CCM
2023-07-25 11:40:23.593 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker     |  | [LOCAL] [dev] [3.11.2] Prefer IPv4 stack is true, prefer IPv6 addresses is false
2023-07-25 11:40:23.601 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker     |  | [LOCAL] [dev] [3.11.2] Picked [10.112.5.51]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
2023-07-25 11:40:23.642 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | com.hazelcast.system                     |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Hazelcast 3.11.2 (20190216 - e302506) starting at [10.112.5.51]:5701
2023-07-25 11:40:23.643 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | com.hazelcast.system                     |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Copyright (c) 2008-2019, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2023-07-25 11:40:23.643 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | com.hazelcast.instance.Node              |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] A non-empty group password is configured for the Hazelcast member. Starting with Hazelcast version 3.8.2, members with the same group name, but with different group passwords (that do not use authentication) form a cluster. The group password configuration will be removed completely in a future release.
2023-07-25 11:40:24.218 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.s.i.o.impl.BackpressureRegulator     |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Backpressure is disabled
2023-07-25 11:40:25.203 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Kubernetes Discovery properties: { service-dns: null, service-dns-timeout: 5, service-name: forecast-mgmt, service-port: 5701, service-label: null, service-label-value: true, namespace: qa-forecast-mgmt, resolve-not-ready-addresses: false, kubernetes-master: https://kubernetes.default.svc}
2023-07-25 11:40:25.210 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Kubernetes Discovery activated resolver: KubernetesApiEndpointResolver
2023-07-25 11:40:25.341 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | com.hazelcast.instance.Node              |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Activating Discovery SPI Joiner
2023-07-25 11:40:25.693 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Starting 7 partition threads and 4 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2023-07-25 11:40:25.703 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics     |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Diagnostics started
2023-07-25 11:40:25.704 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.internal.diagnostics.BuildInfoPlugin |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active
2023-07-25 11:40:25.704 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.i.diagnostics.SystemPropertiesPlugin |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active
2023-07-25 11:40:25.705 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.i.diagnostics.ConfigPropertiesPlugin |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active
2023-07-25 11:40:25.709 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.internal.diagnostics.MetricsPlugin   |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active, period-millis:60000
2023-07-25 11:40:25.711 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.i.diagnostics.SlowOperationPlugin    |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active, period-millis:60000
2023-07-25 11:40:25.712 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | .h.i.d.MemberHazelcastInstanceInfoPlugin |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active, period-millis:60000
2023-07-25 11:40:25.713 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.internal.diagnostics.SystemLogPlugin |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active: logPartitions:false
2023-07-25 11:40:25.718 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | .h.i.d.MemberHazelcastInstanceInfoPlugin |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active, period-millis:10000
2023-07-25 11:40:25.718 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.i.d.OperationHeartbeatPlugin         |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active: period-millis:10000 max-deviation:33%
2023-07-25 11:40:25.722 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] [10.112.5.51]:5701 is STARTING
2023-07-25 11:40:25.756 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [1] retrying in 1 seconds...
2023-07-25 11:40:27.262 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [2] retrying in 2 seconds...
2023-07-25 11:40:29.519 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [3] retrying in 3 seconds...
2023-07-25 11:40:32.899 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [4] retrying in 5 seconds...
2023-07-25 11:40:32.995 | forecast-management-service | hz.jobEngine-hazelcast-kubernetes.IO.thread-in-0 | INFO  | com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection    |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Connection[id=1, /10.112.5.51:5701->/10.112.4.237:44935, endpoint=null, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
2023-07-25 11:40:37.967 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [5] retrying in 7 seconds...
2023-07-25 11:40:43.236 | forecast-management-service | hz.jobEngine-hazelcast-kubernetes.IO.thread-in-1 | INFO  | com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection    |  | [10.112.5.51]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Connection[id=2, /10.112.5.51:5701->/10.112.4.208:32261, endpoint=null, alive=false, type=NONE] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
```

**EDIT 1:**

After removing the port Externalising tag , The Logs for default Kubernetes Behaviour is added below. It says some WARNING related to Zone Aware .
Recently we had changed the Git Repo of the Project but `ServiceName` and `Namespace` are correctly mapped .

````
2023-07-25 13:20:44.153 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Kubernetes Discovery properties: { service-dns: null, service-dns-timeout: 5, service-name: forecast-mgmt, service-port: 5701, service-label: null, service-label-value: true, namespace: qa-forecast-mgmt, resolve-not-ready-addresses: false, kubernetes-master: https://kubernetes.default.svc}
2023-07-25 13:20:44.160 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Kubernetes Discovery activated resolver: KubernetesApiEndpointResolver
2023-07-25 13:20:44.281 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | com.hazelcast.instance.Node              |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Activating Discovery SPI Joiner
2023-07-25 13:20:44.618 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Starting 7 partition threads and 4 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2023-07-25 13:20:44.629 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics     |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Diagnostics started
2023-07-25 13:20:44.630 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.internal.diagnostics.BuildInfoPlugin |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active
2023-07-25 13:20:44.631 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.i.diagnostics.SystemPropertiesPlugin |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active
2023-07-25 13:20:44.631 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.i.diagnostics.ConfigPropertiesPlugin |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active
2023-07-25 13:20:44.634 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.internal.diagnostics.MetricsPlugin   |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active, period-millis:60000
2023-07-25 13:20:44.636 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.i.diagnostics.SlowOperationPlugin    |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active, period-millis:60000
2023-07-25 13:20:44.636 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | .h.i.d.MemberHazelcastInstanceInfoPlugin |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active, period-millis:60000
2023-07-25 13:20:44.638 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.internal.diagnostics.SystemLogPlugin |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active: logPartitions:false
2023-07-25 13:20:44.643 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | .h.i.d.MemberHazelcastInstanceInfoPlugin |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active, period-millis:10000
2023-07-25 13:20:44.643 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | c.h.i.d.OperationHeartbeatPlugin         |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Plugin:active: period-millis:10000 max-deviation:33%
2023-07-25 13:20:44.646 | forecast-management-service | main | INFO  | com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] [10.112.5.131]:5701 is STARTING
2023-07-25 13:20:44.679 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [1] retrying in 1 seconds...
2023-07-25 13:20:46.184 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [2] retrying in 2 seconds...
2023-07-25 13:20:48.443 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [3] retrying in 3 seconds...
2023-07-25 13:20:51.823 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [4] retrying in 5 seconds...
2023-07-25 13:20:56.893 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [5] retrying in 7 seconds...
2023-07-25 13:21:04.492 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [6] retrying in 11 seconds...
2023-07-25 13:21:15.890 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [7] retrying in 17 seconds...
2023-07-25 13:21:32.978 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [8] retrying in 25 seconds...
2023-07-25 13:21:58.610 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [9] retrying in 38 seconds...
2023-07-25 13:22:37.056 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [10] retrying in 57 seconds...
2023-07-25 13:23:34.725 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService     |  | [10.112.5.131]:5701 [dev] [3.11.2] Cannot fetch the current zone, ZONE_AWARE feature is disabled
2023-07-25 13:23:34.733 | forecast-management-service | main | WARN  | com.hazelcast.kubernetes.RetryUtils      |  | Couldn't connect to the Kubernetes master, [1] retrying in 1 seconds...```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check the provided answers and accept them if they address the solution otherwise feel free to leave comment.

Comment: @Lunatic Edited the above question for the updated logs with Default Kubernetes Config. Also , can u tell me u need to view the deployment config or service config ? –

Answer (score 0):

Let imagine you don't have network connectivity problem, so as warning suggests, Hazelcast [client](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/blob/master/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/kubernetes/RetryUtils.java) failed to connect to the Kubernetes master API server which can cause from  misconfiguration of Hazelcast client or the Kubernetes cluster.
Here are some work arounds,

- Try restarting the Hazelcast client and the Kubernetes API server pod `kubectl delete pod 'the-pod-name' -n 'the-namespace'` which cause a brief interruption in service while the new pod is being created and started. However if you have multiple replicas of the API server pod running, you can use a rolling update strategy to update the pods.(This is mostly happens in my experience)
- Make sure that `ServiceName` and `Namespace` properties are set correctly within Hazelcast client configuration .
- Check the Kubernetes configuration file or possible network connectivity issues.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick response . 
1. I have tried scaling down all pods and scaling them back again . The issue Still persists .
2. ServiceName and Namespace are correctly Set .
3. What should I check in Kubernetes Config File ?

Comment: @PrateekGoel i guess i may need more details then, leave an other question with you configuration properties, specifically the modified options from defaults.

Comment: Edited the above question for the updated logs with Default Kubernetes Config. Also , can u tell me u need to view the deployment config or service config ?